# Hyperlink not properly showing in a td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, siebel

I am able to  create a `hyperlink` of the `td` element but whenever I click in the blank space inside the `td` cell, the html code(`<a href>` tag that is dynamically added) shows up replacing the data of the `td`.It works fine when I click on the text of the `td` but not works if I click in the blank space of that `td` cell. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Below is my code snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#s_1_l').find("tr").each(function() {
           $(this).find("td").eq(2).html("<a href='#'>"+$(this).find("td").eq(2).text()+"</a>");                  
             }); 
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Chiranjit

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. When you click the text in the `td` the link text is replaced with `<a href>`? Could you set up a http://jsfiddle.net to recreate the problem?

Comment: I am doing this in an applet that is generated by Siebel(Open UI). I don't have any html page to work with. Only through JS I need to add this dynamic href tag for a particular column so that clicking on the text (not in the blank space inside td cell) will open a new window.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to create hyperlink?
Sorry but it does not make too much sense, if you want to attache some function to those TD elements, which triggers on click, than you should just attache a listener to those TD elements. Since you are already using jQuery use something like this:

```
$("#s_1_l td:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
// what should be done when the users clicks
});

//make the cursor a pointer for it.
$("#s_1_l td:nth-child(3)").css("cursor","pointer");
```

This is way lighter in resource than looping trough each set and add a href's.

See and example: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VeYRV/)

Comment: Thanks for your help.but all I want is to make the text inside the td hyperlink and clicking on that it will take him to a specific url.But here I see the whole td being hyperlinked. In the code that I mentioned above I got it right, except whenever I click in the blank space in the td cell, the dynamically added html code shows up replacing the text of the td.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can try with this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#s_1_l').find("tr").each(function() {
        $(this).find("td").eq(2).html('<a href="javascript:;">'+$(this).find("td").eq(2).text()+'</a>');
   });
});
```

if not, please, show your html code.

Answer (score 0):

With css you can try this:

```
td {
  padding: 0;
}

td a {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RQVYG/1/)

or maybe you cloud just bind a click event directly on your `td`:

```
$('#s_1_l').find("tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find("td").eq(2).addClass('td-link');
    $(this).find("td").eq(2).click(function () {
        // do things
       console.log($(this).html())
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RQVYG/4/)